# Unable to read some parts of the PDF document using iText

Tags: itext, itext7

I have a bunch of PDF documents and I am generally able to read all of the documents using the method `iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage`

Some of the documents have a block of text which is not being read.
E.g. In the picture attached, I am unable to read text in the region encircled with yellow.

I guess, that this is entity is not a picture because I am unable to copy paste using the mouse. Also, I am able to  read images in the document by handling `EventType.RENDER_IMAGE` in a custom strategy object. And, the encircled region does not get extracted as an image.

Any suggestions on how this could be read?

Thanks,
Sau
[image]

Comment: As that appears neither to be text nor bitmap image, it most likely is drawn using vector graphics instructions.  You can also retrieve such instructions, but what you'd get is a sequence of path definition (move to, line to, curve to,...) and path rendering (stroke, fill,...) information. Would that help you?

Comment: Hi mkl, Please post your comment as a proposed answer so that I can award you points? Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get neither a `RENDER_TEXT` nor a `RENDER_IMAGE` event for that content, it most likely is drawn using vector graphics instructions.

You can also retrieve such instructions, but what you'd get is a sequence of path definition (move to, line to, curve to,...) and path rendering (stroke, fill,...) information as `RENDER_PATH` events.